# How to execute a ZeroMQ PUSH/PULL archetype in an asynchronous way?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, zeromq, pyzmq, python-3.8

I want to initiate a `PULL` in a port and want to receive from other ports to my `PULL` port. In the case of a `PULL` port, it listens asynchronously and when it receives a message, it just prints the message in the console. So for that I have written a method inside a `Push`-class, which will send the message to the `PULL` port.

My code is as follows :

```
import random
import zmq
import time
import sys
import string
import asyncio
import zmq.asyncio

class Push():
    def __init__(self, port, addr='localhost'):
        self.port = port
        self.addr = addr

        self.ctx = zmq.Context()
        self.scoket = self.ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
        self.scoket.connect(f'tcp://{self.addr}:{selfa.port}')

    def send(self):
        chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase
        message = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(4))
        self.scoket.send(bytes(message, 'utf-8'))
        print(f'sending: {message}')

class Pull():
    def __init__(self, port, addr='*'):
        self.port = port
        self.addr = addr

        self.ctx = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.ctx.socket(zmq.PULL)
        self.socket.bind(f'tcp://{self.addr}:{self.port}')

    async def listen(self, listener):
        while True:
            string = await self.socket.recv()
            listener(string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    push = Push('55501')

    async def send():
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            print('Sending...')
            push.send()

    pull = Pull('55501')

    try:
        asyncio.run(
            pull.listen(print),
            send(),
        )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('exiting...')
        exit()
```

The above code is not running. The code stops at the listen method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#ADAPTED FROM PYMATA EXPRESS EXAMPLE CONCURRENTTAKS
#https://github.com/MrYsLab/pymata-express/
import asyncio
import zmq
import json
import zmq.asyncio as zmq_asyncio
from pymata_express.pymata_express import PymataExpress


class ConcurrentTasks:

    def __init__(self, board):


        self.loop = board.get_event_loop()
        self.board = board

        self.ctxsync = zmq.Context()
        self.context = zmq.asyncio.Context()
        self.rep = self.context.socket(zmq.REP)
        self.rep.bind("tcp://*:5558")

        self.trigger_pin = 53
        self.echo_pin = 51

        loop.run_until_complete(self.async_init_and_run())

    ### START:  NEW CODE THAT RESOLVED THE ISSUE
    async def pingsonar(self):
        value = await self.board.sonar_read(self.trigger_pin)
        return value

    async def readsonar(self):
        while True:
            rep_recv = await self.rep.recv() 
            value = await asyncio.wait([self.pingsonar()])
            valuesonar = list(value[0])[0].result()
            json_data = json.dumps(valuesonar) 
            await self.rep.send(json_data.encode()) 
            await asyncio.sleep(1 / 1000) #maybe this line isn't necessary

    ### END : NEW CODE THAT RESOLVED THE ISSUE

    async def async_init_and_run(self):

        await self.board.set_pin_mode_sonar(self.trigger_pin, self.echo_pin)

        readsonar = asyncio.create_task(self.readsonar())
        await readsonar

        # OTHER CREATED_TASK GO HERE, (removed them in the MVE, but they work fine)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    my_board = PymataExpress()
    try:
        ConcurrentTasks(my_board)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, RuntimeError):
        loop.run_until_complete(my_board.shutdown())
        print('goodbye')
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Comment: In class push send method is synchronous  but  in class pull listen method is asynchronous. In the main function i am converting the send method to async for continuous pushing of string. I want to send and receive asynchronously, which is not happening.

Comment: @SushabanDebnath Lets make both send and listen or receive async. I used pymataexpress.

Comment: With all due respect, the problem is somewhere else in the source code + it is a sign of poor engineering to "solve" a solvable problem by **re-wrapping** the original problem into another layer of abstraction ( using one more layer from another framework ). The ZeroMQ per-se is an asynchronous, high-performance, low-latency optimised framework, so not using its tools right is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: **Re-wrapping a poorly crafted code into another framework may relieve some problems, yet at immense costs and penalties from even poorer performance and worse error-trace-ability for maintaining such repositories in next months and years**. Smart & clean design practices are **The Right Solution**, not hiding a problematic concept ( expressed in a piece of code ) just into another black-box

Answer (score 0):

> *The above code is not running.*

The code is running,
yet there are mistakes ( in concept ) and typos in the source code.

The code as-is inhibits the **`Push`**-class from ever become **`.connect()`**-ed, thus the `Pull`-counterparty `.bind()`-s, yet has nobody to talk to.

---

### SOLUTION

**1 )**
Repair this typo ( + better, explicitly detect and handle all potential error-states )

```
self.scoket.connect(f'tcp://{self.addr}:{selfa.port}') # this will NEVER FLY
#--------------------------------------------^
self.scoket.connect(f'tcp://{self.addr}:{self.port}')  # this will ... ( + detect Error-state(s)
```

**2 )**
Correct the concept - mixing low-hanging fruits ( several asynchronous frameworks used at once, one working against all the others ) is a sign of shallow understanding of the responsibility of professional engineering in reliable and robust-enough **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)** ( flaws in the concept of control, like during landing Apollo-11 on Moon or, on the contrary, the Chernobyl-kind of mis-management system + mentality, are clean, inspiring and warning enough examples how bad practices *( if not prohibited + detected + corrected + penalised )* can & ***will harm** again and again and again* ).

---

### The Best Next Step

If you are keen to get to the professional-level, start with Pieter Hintjens' book "Code Connected, Volume 1" - worth time, worth efforts, worth understanding their discussed concepts.